Create a custom Windows folder with features across Picture, Music, Video, Desktop, Documents
Is it possible to add a create a custom Windows folder with the same features properties of Special Windows Folder like Picture, Music, Video, Desktop, Documents; the similarity they have appears in viewing their property in context menu [right click file and sel;ect property]. You'll find under the location tab a button to relocate the file content elsewhere than dcurrently configured. Basically, they seem to behave like symbolic links to a place usuially in the C:\Users{username}

What "features"?

You can create a folder and create a symbolic link to that folder but you cannot create a folders that is anywhere near as integrated as those user profiles directories.
